# How do I edit a message using an image in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot using discord.py and want to edit a message that my bot sent and is text and replace the text with an image. Most of the thing I have tried give me an error and I couldn't find this anywhere else.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please share some of the code that you have tried out, or at least some of the sources you have checked? This will help us answer your question better, and help you get an answer faster. You can also visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what you would use to edit a message. You must save the message to a variable then you may edit it later. Look at the code below, to execute the command it's `?test` and will edit that message.

```py
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", case_insensitive=True)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("I'm message 1")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await message.edit(content="I'm message 2")


bot.run(token)
```

Comment: I know how to edit a message normally, but I am trying to edit an image that currently contains text into an image.

Comment: @AniketW download the image, use PIL and upload it again